# C - add decimal place and round int above 999

Tags: c

I have an integer number that corresponds with a file size in bytes. An int that returned 400 would be 400 bytes in size, and an int that returned 10400 would be 10.4 KB. What I want to do is convert an int like 10400 to 10.4 and also have a way to distinguish between 10.4 KB, 10.4 MB, or 10.4 GB for example. Because 10400 is 10.4 KB, 10400000 is 10.4 MB, and 10400000000 is 10.4 GB. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You do know how to do that with math? Then just write it down as code. It really is that simple as you’re doing it in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
void pretty_bytes(char* buf, uint bytes)
{
    const char* suffixes[7];
    suffixes[0] = "B";
    suffixes[1] = "KB";
    suffixes[2] = "MB";
    suffixes[3] = "GB";
    suffixes[4] = "TB";
    suffixes[5] = "PB";
    suffixes[6] = "EB";
    uint s = 0; // which suffix to use
    double count = bytes;
    while (count >= 1024 && s < 7)
    {
        s++;
        count /= 1024;
    }
    if (count - floor(count) == 0.0)
        sprintf(buf, "%d %s", (int)count, suffixes[s]);
    else
        sprintf(buf, "%.1f %s", count, suffixes[s]);
}
```

[Source](https://www.mbeckler.org/blog/?p=114)

If you don't want to use buffer:

```
static const char *humanSize(uint64_t bytes)
{
    char *suffix[] = {"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    char length = sizeof(suffix) / sizeof(suffix[0]);

    int i = 0;
    double dblBytes = bytes;

    if (bytes > 1024) {
        for (i = 0; (bytes / 1024) > 0 && i<length-1; i++, bytes /= 1024)
            dblBytes = bytes / 1024.0;
    }

    static char output[200];
    sprintf(output, "%.02lf %s", dblBytes, suffix[i]);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You should usually leave an attribution [Pretty printing a number of bytes in C/C++](https://www.mbeckler.org/blog/?p=114)

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. New to writing answers here.